# Return random order of list items on form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jqueryform

I am submitting a search form via ajax and returning the results from another page into a ul element. I am wondering how to return the li elements in a random order. I am using something called jquery form to get this done.

AJAX:

```
$(function() {
    $("#js-form").ajaxForm({
        success: function(data, txtStatus, jqXHR) {
            alert(data);
            $("#js-results").empty();
            $(data).children("li").appendTo("#js-results");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: What's the reason you can't do the random ordering from the server side?

Comment: @BasharAbdullah I am not able to write server side code on the platform I use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [shuffle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6274381/2241893) function:

```
$(function() {
    $("#js-form").ajaxForm({
        success: function(data, txtStatus, jqXHR) {
            var resultsObj = $("#js-results");
            resultsObj.empty();
            $(shuffle($(data).children("li"))).appendTo(resultsObj);
        }
    });
});
```